# Django 2.1 Create automatically models in db

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I have 2 models :

```
class Solo(models.Model):
     id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
     atleta = models.ForeignKey(Atleta, 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     tipo = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
     valida = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
     societa = models.ForeignKey(Societa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     gara = models.ForeignKey(Evento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     path = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

and

```
class VotazioniSolo(models.Model):
     solo = models.OneToOneField(Solo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     voto_1 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_2 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_3 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_4 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_5 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_6 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_7 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_8 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_9 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_10 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_11 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_12 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_13 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_14 = models.FloatField(default=0)
     voto_15 = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Inside the table of db, I have a lot of Solo objects and I need Django create for me every Object VotazioniSolo for every Solo existing.

And if I create an other object Solo, automatically Django create the respective VotazioneSolo object with default values.

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you specify your question? For ForeignKeys Django Create additional table to handle the Relations

Comment: either override save method of Solo model to create a VotazioniSolo instance everytime a Solo is created, or use post_save signal to do so

Comment: Great, I used signal and works fine! Thaks